# Atmel Studio atprogram.exe throws TCF Error code 131120

Tags: command-line-interface, atmel, atmelstudio

I try to read the device information from an AT32UC3B1128 (using an jtagicemkii) like this

```
atprogram.exe -v -i JTAG -d AT32UC3B1128 -cl 100khz info
```

Doing this on my workstation, I get the following output (containing an error message at the bottom):

```
StdOut: 

Firmware check OK
Tool jtagicemkii has firmware version: 07.27
Target voltage: 3.35 V

Device information:

Name:       AT32UC3B1128  
JtagId:     0x81ee703f    
Revision:   I             
CPU arch.:  AVR32_UC3     
Series:     

Security bit is not set.

Memory Information:

Address Space    StartAddress            Size

sysreg                    0x0           0x400

dbgreg                    0x0           0x400

base                      0x0     0x100000000
  FLASH            0x80000000         0x20000
  USER_PAGE        0x80800000           0x200
  SRAM                    0x0          0x8000
  USBB_SLAVE       0xd0000000        0x800000
  IO               0xfffe0000         0x20000

fuses              0xfffe1410             0x4


Fuses:
FGPFRLO (0b11111111111111111111111111111111):
   BODEN         0x3L
   BODHYST       OFF
   BODLEVEL      0x3fL
   BOOTPROT      0x7L
   EPFL          OFF
   LOCK15        OFF
   LOCK14        OFF
   LOCK13        OFF
   LOCK12        OFF
   LOCK11        OFF
   LOCK10        OFF
   LOCK9         OFF
   LOCK8         OFF
   LOCK7         OFF
   LOCK6         OFF
   LOCK5         OFF
   LOCK4         OFF
   LOCK3         OFF
   LOCK2         OFF
   LOCK1         OFF
   LOCK0         OFF

StdErr: 

[DEBUG] Starting execution of "info"
[DEBUG] Starting process 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\atbackend\atbackend.exe'
[DEBUG] Connecting to TCP:127.0.0.1:49811
[INFO] Connected to jtagicemkii, fw version: 7.27
[INFO] Firmware check OK
[ERROR] Error in TCF lockbit format. Missed key Could not get Module LOCKBIT for AT32UC3B1128. (TCF Error code: 131120)
[DEBUG] Command "info" finished with return code 0
[DEBUG] Exit successfully.
```

As you can see, the following error message is output to standard error:

```
[ERROR] Error in TCF lockbit format. Missed key Could not get Module LOCKBIT for AT32UC3B1128. (TCF Error code: 131120)
```

I have no clue how to resolve this error and couldn't find anything useful searching for similar error messages.

I tried it on another PC with the same programmer and hardware and it works fine. The only obvious difference are different versions of Atmel Studio. I have installed the latest version 7.0.1417, while the other PC uses 7.0.1006.

Any ideas?

PS: Atmel Studio itself seems to be working fine. I have no trouble reading fuses and lockbits from the GUI. Also, erasing/programming from command line is working fine as well. Judging from the error, it seems to be something specific to "lockbit format" due to the missing "lockbit module".

Answer (score 0):

I got an official [response from Atmel](http://www.avrfreaks.net/comment/2182561#comment-2182561) over at AvrFreaks regarding this problem:

> We've already fixed this internally. Unfortunately, it won't be available until the next release (was a bit more than just DFP updates, bug AVRSV-7837).